# AnimatedSwitcher not working as intended? Widget changing but no animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Goal: Press a button and have it switch to another page with an animated transition.

For that, I'm using AnimatedSwitcher.

Below is my code:

```
class WelcomeScreenSwitcher extends State<RandomWords>{
  Widget calledWidget;

  void switchPage(int newNumber, context) {
    if (newNumber == 1) {
      setState(() {calledWidget = welcomeScreen(context);},);
    } else if (newNumber == 2) {
      setState(() {calledWidget = learnMoreScreen(context);},);}
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (calledWidget == null) {
      switchPage(1, context);
    }
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
      child: calledWidget,
    );

  Widget welcomeScreen(context){
    return Scaffold({body: Column(children: [
      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {switchPage(2, context);}, child: Text('B'),),],
        );
      });
    }

  Widget learnMoreScreen(context){
    return Scaffold({body: Column(children: [
      RaisedButton(onPressed: () {switchPage(2, context);}, child: Text('B'),),],
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

The code is functional. It does actually switch between the two pages, but there's no animation to go with it.

At some point during development, I was getting the animation, but then it just stopped happening and I can't find out why. I don't remember changing anything specific about how I call the AnimatedSwitcher.

If it's of any use, hot reloading also doesn't work anymore. I need to Restart the app to have ANY change register. It used to function properly before beginning work on the AnimatedSwitcher.

Comment: refactor your methods into actual classes. That should fix it.

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you please give a small example on how that would look like?

Comment: @RémiRousselet could you please explain why the methods don't work but actual class do?

Comment: @EmilAdz methods don't create a new BuildContext. Classes do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this

```
class _AniSwitchState extends State<AniSwitch> {
  Widget calledWidget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void switchPage(int newNumber) {
      if (newNumber == 1) {
        setState(() {calledWidget = WelcomeScreen();},);
      } else if (newNumber == 2) {
        setState(() {calledWidget = LearnMoreScreen();},);}
    }

      if (calledWidget == null) {
        switchPage(1);
      }

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
          child: calledWidget
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Increment'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              switchPage(2);
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("Welcome"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class LearnMoreScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("hello world"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is works, but looks like some workaround, anyone has another solution?

Answer (score 113):

**If the new widget you're switching in, is the same type as previous widget, set the `key` property to another value to get that animation**

for example, this `AnimatedSwitcher` doesn't work:

```dart
  AnimatedSwitcher(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    child: (condition)
        ? Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        : Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
  );
```

Because we want to switch between two `Container`s, and `AnimatedSwitcher` can't understand the difference of them, so it doesn't animate their switch.
If we set different `key` property in those `Container`s, then `AnimatedSwitcher` can understand they are different and does animate their switch.

Just like this:

```dart
  AnimatedSwitcher(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    child: (condition)
        ? Container(
            key: ValueKey<int>(0),
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        : Container(
            key: ValueKey<int>(1),
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
  );
```

Comment: wasted hours just for this, thanks man! but how do you know this?

Comment: they mention it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKKgYpC-EPQ&ab_channel=Flutter

Comment: You saved me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would never have figured this out.

Comment: How to avoid "duplicated key" issue while switching very fast before the animation is over?

Comment: Hi @yellowgray, using `UniqueKey()` for children is the easiest solution, but in this case, it has some drawbacks, one of which is that when you rebuild your `AnimatedSwitcher` widget without even changing its child, it animates its child. To avoid that, you can define an int variable (let's name it counter), and every time you want to swap your child, increment it by two, then use `ValueKey(counter)` for the first child and `ValueKey(counter+1)` for the second child. Therefore, unwanted animations will also disappear ;)

Comment: @yellowgray You can also use `AnimatedCrossFade` without worrying about "duplicated key" issue!

Comment: This answer needs to be marked as the correct one, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

i am also having this issue and couldn´t solve since few days, i gave different keys to my Widgets even i used AnimatedSwitcher´s `layoutBuilder` to wrap front widget around a `Conrainer()` that has given `UniqueKey()` every time it has changed so maybe it would work but it still no use.

My Code;

```
           RxInt currentTab = 0.obs;

           RxList<Map<String, Widget>> stepList = [
             {
               'title': Text('Adres Bilgisi'),
               'view': Step1(key: ValueKey(1),)
             },
             {
               'title': Text('Adres Bilgisi'),
               'view': Step2(key: ValueKey(2),),
             },
             {
               'title': Text('Gönderi Detayı'),
               'view': Step3(key: ValueKey(3),),
             }
           ].obs;

           SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Obx(() => AnimatedSwitcher(
                key: Key('switcher.tab'),
                duration: new Duration(microseconds: 500),
                switchInCurve: Curves.easeIn,
                layoutBuilder: (currentChild, previousChildren) {
                  return Container(
                    key: UniqueKey(),
                    child: AnimatedSwitcher.defaultLayoutBuilder(currentChild, previousChildren),
                  );
                },
                transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                  /*final offsetAnimation = Tween(
                  begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
                  end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                ).animate(animation);
                // 3.
                return ClipRect(
                  child: SlideTransition(
                    position: offsetAnimation,
                    child: child,
                  ),
                );*/
                  return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
                },
                child: controller.tabs[controller.currentTab.value.toInt()],
              )),
            )
```

This is the TabBar code that i change current selected widget;

```
            TabBarWidget(
              height: 60,
              initialSelectedId: 0,
              tag: 'advertform.tab',
              tabs: [
                ChipWidget(
                  tag: 'advertform.tab',
                  text: "1".tr,
                  id: 0,
                  onSelected: (id) {
                    controller.prevStep.value = controller.onStep.value;
                    controller.onStep.value = id;
                    controller.changeTab(id);
                  },
                ),
                ChipWidget(
                  tag: 'advertform.tab',
                  text: "2".tr,
                  id: 1,
                  onSelected: (id) {
                    controller.prevStep.value = controller.onStep.value;
                    controller.onStep.value = id;
                    controller.changeTab(id);
                  },
                ),
                ChipWidget(
                  tag: 'advertform.tab',
                  text: "3".tr,
                  id: 2,
                  onSelected: (id) {
                    controller.prevStep.value = controller.onStep.value;
                    controller.onStep.value = id;
                    controller.changeTab(id);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )

            void changeTab(int index) {
              currentTab.value = index;
            }
```